# Order by Timestamp, but limit by most recent date

Tags: mysql

I have a table with IDs, product names and a TIMESTAMP field including 'ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'. Hence, everytime a product is touched the timestamp gets the most recent timestamp.

The table is imported and I am trying to only get the most recent addition and can't remove the old data.

Simplified table below:

```
ID, Product, timestamp
 1,       A, 2016-10-20 15:10:39
 2,       B, 2016-09-10 12:41:21
 3,       C, 2016-10-20 15:11:55
 4,       D, 2016-08-01 16:18:21
 5,       E, 2016-10-19 10:00:12
 6,       F, 2016-09-10 12:41:20
```

I am trying to get the following output:

```
ID, Product, timestamp
 1,       A, 2016-10-20 15:10:39
 3,       C, 2016-10-20 15:11:55
```

Basically I don't care about the time portion of timestamp... only the date. Is there a way to limit the output to the most recent date in the timestamp field, no matter what the actual current date is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach uses a subquery to identify the maximum (most recent) date, and then restricts to only records which share this date:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE DATE(timestamp) = (SELECT MAX(DATE(timestamp)) FROM yourTable)
-- ORDER BY timestamp  (or whatever column you want to use for ordering)
```

Comment: i will test, but this sorts the whole timestamp does it not? ID 1 and 3 have the same date but different timestamps?

Comment: This query meets your requirement as far as I know.  Please try it and then come back here if there be any problems.